# How can I reference a component in a Bundle?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3

I have a **bootstrapper** project in which I do a **registry search** to check if the program installed is `32bit` or `64bit` in order to install a driver of the correct platform.

I would like to use a variable in the **key** called `[PRODUCTNAME]` *( Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany\[PRODUCTNAME]" )* that is defined in the `Registry.wxs` file as a **RegistryValue** within a **component** and used in various `Product.wxs` files in my solution. How can I reference it in my `Bundle.wxs`?

So far I have tried this:

```
<util:ComponentGroupRef Id="RegistryComponents" />
```

In the `Bundle` tag above my **registry searches**, and this in a `Fragment` under the `Bundle`:

```
<Fragment>
     <ComponentGroup Id="RegistryComponents">
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="Registry" />
     </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

But I get this error: `The Bundle element contains an unexpected child element 'util:ComponentGroupRef'.`

In my `Product.wxs` files the **component** is simply referenced like this:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MainApp" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Registry"/>
</Feature>
```

Is there a nice way of referencing that variable in my `Bundle`? I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

No. Bundles (installed by the Burn engine) use separate searches from MSI packages (installed by the Windows Installer engine). Also, Bundles use `Variable` and MSIs use `Property` for "variables" during the install (again, because different engines).

Comment: Ok thanks. If I can't reference that exact variable, can I achieve the same thing in the Bundle some other way, like do a registry search? Or must I hardcode the product name?

Comment: Bind variable or preprocessor variable should both work. The Deployment Dojo walks through all these options. Episode 18 is the summary episode (https://www.youtube.com/live/d4DEPW-RO30?feature=share), but you might jump back a few episodes if you need more background. It's about Package but many concepts work for Bundles too.